# How to implement a Recycler View with CardView in a Fragment [Android - Java]?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

There are quite a few tutorials about this online. However, I've tried many and none of them could do what I expected properly.

I'm very new to Android and App development, but have some experience developing websites and API's. I have developed a website and wanted to create a simple Android app to show a feed of events for the users.

So after some research, it seems the best way to handle efficiently big lists of JSON Data coming from an API is with RecyclerView, and CardViews would boost up a little the design.

So I setup a project with a bottom navbar and have created three tabs (Events, Profile and Notifications). These tabs return a Fragment and the List should be inside the Events Fragment. I have hardcoded it to display 5 items, but it never shows up the cards. So I'm not sure where its wrong. The other fragments show up correctly

Here's my code:

**BaseFragment**

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content);

        if(fragment == null){
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.events_fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }


    }
}
```

**Events Fragment, Adapter and ViewHolder**

```
public class EventsRecyclerFragment extends Fragment{

    public static Fragment newInstance(){
        return new EventsRecyclerFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_recycler_view_fragment, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new EventsRecyclerViewAdapter());
        return view;

    }

    private class EventsRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CardView mCardView;
        private TextView mTextView;

        public EventsRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        public EventsRecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_card_view, container, false));
            mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.events_card_container);

        }
    }

    private class EventsRecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsRecyclerViewHolder>{

        @Override
        public EventsRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            return new EventsRecyclerViewHolder(inflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(EventsRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

**How I'm using on Activity**

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preferences";
    private static final String PREF_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    private static final String PREF_TOKEN = "TOKEN";
    Button btnLogout;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();


            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_events:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new EventsRecyclerFragment().newInstance()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new UserFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new NotificationsFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    }

}
```

Could anyone help me on how would I make this basic list show up?
Thanks in advance

Comment: post your xml from Fragment

Answer (score 1):

Two changes are required :

1. `UserActivity` : Remove the `new` keyword from `EventsRecyclerFragment()` instance initialization as the `newInstance()` method returns a new instance itself.

   ```
   public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preferences";
     private static final String PREF_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
     private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
     private static final String PREF_TOKEN = "TOKEN";
     Button btnLogout;
     private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
         = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();


         switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.navigation_events:
                   transaction.replace(R.id.content, EventsRecyclerFragment().newInstance()).commit();
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_profile:
                   transaction.replace(R.id.content, new UserFragment()).commit();
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                   transaction.replace(R.id.content, new NotificationsFragment()).commit();
                   return true;
         }
         return false;
       }
     };

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       BottomNavigationView navigation =  findViewById(R.id.navigation);
       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

     }

   }
   ```
2. EventsRecyclerFragment : Always set `orientation` of recycler view during its initialization.

   ```
    public class EventsRecyclerFragment extends Fragment{

           public static Fragment newInstance(){
               return new EventsRecyclerFragment();
           }

           @Nullable
           @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_recycler_view_fragment, container, false);

               RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);
               LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
         linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(new EventsRecyclerViewAdapter());
               return view;

           }

           private class EventsRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
               private CardView mCardView;
               private TextView mTextView;

               public EventsRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
                   super(itemView);
               }

               public EventsRecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
                   super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_card_view, container, false));
                   mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.events_card_container);

               }
           }

           private class EventsRecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsRecyclerViewHolder>{

               @Override
               public EventsRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                   return new EventsRecyclerViewHolder(inflater, parent);
               }

               @Override
               public void onBindViewHolder(EventsRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

               }

               @Override
               public int getItemCount() {
                   return 5;
               }
           }
       }
   ```